# Solve $y' + \frac1y + \frac1x =0$ Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Do you have any suggestions for how to sole this differential equation?
$y'+\frac1x + \frac1y =0$ 
? :)
I tried solving this by changing variable in the form of $v=x^\alpha*y^\beta$ but it didn't work! 
Do you have any other ideas?! :)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y'+\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y}=0$

$y\dfrac{dy}{dx}+\dfrac{y}{x}=-1$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $x=e^{-t}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{-e^{-t}}=-e^t\dfrac{dy}{dt}$

$\therefore-e^ty\dfrac{dy}{dt}+e^ty=-1$

$y\dfrac{dy}{dt}-y=e^{-t}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf